# How to hide a DIV element using RegEx and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I would like to hide all other element except `class="imagebrowser"` in following,

```
<div class="entry">
    <p>Heading 1</p>
    <p>Heading 2</p>
        ...
    <p>Heading n</p>
    <b>This is abold text</b>
    <div>This is a div element</div>

    <div class="imagebrowser">
        Hello world
    </div>
</div>
```

Expected result,

```
<div class="entry">

    <div class="imagebrowser">
        Hello world
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('div.entry div').not('.imagebrowser').hide();
```

This will hide all divs inside the "entry" div other than those with the class "imagebrowser".

Comment: but he want to hide all elements, not only divs.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$(".entry").children(":not(.imagebrowser)").hide();
```

Comment: @Kyathi - This answer was much better than what you went for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$('.entry').children().hide();
$('.imagebrowser').show();
```

This should hide all the contents of the entry div, including the p tags, and then show the imagebrowser div afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me. You can replace `$(this).val()` with `#target`

```
$('.'+ $(this).val()).show(); $('.tabcontent2 tr:not(.'+ $(this).val() +')').hide();
```