# Hide TR when TR contains a keyword

Tags: jquery, regex, html-table

I want to hide a **tr** when one of it's **td** contains a part of the keyword "Aufruestung".

E.g. one td has the text "APL Aufruestung 10", I want to find it and hide the complete **tr** - but just the first tr, not all the parents. My first try doesn't work at all, I think i have to do something with RegEx to find all the tr's with "Aufruestung"? I'm not sure and a newbie to jQuery...

```
jQuery('td:contains("Aufruestung"))').closest('tr').hide()
```

Comment: you have an extra ')' in the selector. use like this jQuery('td:contains("Aufruestung")').closest('tr').hide()

Comment: I had the same issue and solved it. Have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51539444/4299200).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("td").each(function() {
var str = 'Aufruestung';
var txt = $(this).html();  
   alert(txt); // to cross verify
    if (/Aufruestung/i.test(txt)){
alert('String Contains Word');

} else {
alert('String Does not contains word');

}  
});
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zHZLK/890/)

Comment: Okay, but this will only check for a td with "Leather", I think. I also want to hide tds with "I like Leather" for example... thats the point that makes it complicated for me...

Comment: This will check, if the td contains the word "Leather" then it will hide its parent row. This will also work fine if that particular word is part of a sentence, as you have mentioned above.

Comment: you can hide the parent tr where alert with `string contains word` comes

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in your code. extra `)` is added in it. also you can check for contains is tr rather than in tds:

```
jQuery('tr:contains(Aufruestung)').hide()
```

Comment: Thank you, i'll play a bit around with the idea and will inform you if it works out...